# Who are these 3 brothers?

Tags: riddle

**Bob**: I’m doing the video speeches for this celebration thanking the three brothers. Do you have anything to say? How have they influenced you?

**Sue**: I’d like to thank them for giving me an intuition that has been invaluable in my daily life. Also, they have given me a general attitude of enthusiasm, and made me more self-sufficient, creative, and spontaneous.

**Bob**: Wow! How else have they affected you?

**Sue**: Well, Aaron has made me adventurous and courageous, Sam has made me more independent and optimistic, and Lenny has made me more confident and loyal.

**Bob**: Great! So… all positives then?

**Sue**: Well, on the other hand, they can make me bossy, quick-tempered, and melodramatic at times, but I am working on that!

---

What are the real names of these brothers, and what are they?

Hint #1

> All three brothers are very warm, no doubt

Comment: Aaron Sam Lenny - ASL - American Sign Language ?!

Comment: Could they be hormones or neurochemicals perhaps?

Comment: Comment on behalf of @WillHansen - Is this a Harry Potter reference?

Comment: Moe How(A)rd, (S)hemp, and (L)arry,  obviously.

Comment: @WillHansen It is not a Harry Potter reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the hint, the three brothers are

> the three Fire signs of the Zodiac. People born under the sign of Aaron/Aries are known to be [adventurous and courageous](http://www.ganeshaspeaks.com/aries/aries-traits.action). People born under the sign of Sam/Sagittarius are more [independent and optimistic](http://www.123newyear.com/zodiac-signs/sagittarius.html). People born under the sign of Lenny/Leo are [confident and loyal](http://www.123newyear.com/zodiac-signs/leo.html).

Also,

> people born under these three fire signs are known to be bossy, quick-tempered, and melodramatic at times.

Comment: I'm having some trouble editing the spoilers. Can someone help?

Comment: I totally posted this first ;-)

Comment: marcman you did, but this had more explanation, and you didn't mention "fire signs", but I still upvoted your answer

Comment: Put a horizontal bar ---- between the two paragraphs. You'll need blank lines separating the bar so it doesn't format as a heading.

Comment: fair enough -- also I fixed your spoilers @rikitikitik. You need text between block quotes or they have to be consecutive lines for it to work--annoying I know

Comment: More detail: According to the tropical zodiac, anyone with ANY of their planets (sun, moon, or other "planets") in fire signs are affected by them

Comment: @JLee Does your comment explain how a person can have 3 signs when they can only be born on one date? (I'm not really familiar with astrology.)

Comment: @pacoverflow. Not really, but I will explain. The tropical zodiac (most used here in America) is based on seasons, not constellations. Divide the sky up into 12 EQUAL parts. Each of the 30 degree slices is a sign. People can not directly BE or HAVE any sign. They interact with the sign only through their "planets." I put that in quotes because the Sun and the Moon are also considered planets. (think of it as "Celestial bodies"). The moment a person is born, his planets are in one of those slices of sky (signs). In the somewhat rare event that a planet is right on the border, it belongs to...

Comment: whichever side it is on the most. In the super rare event that it is exactly even, then it is said to be "on the cusp" and that planet can display qualities from both neighboring signs. The planets move through the signs, which are stationary. Each planet plays a different role in one's life. The planet with the most influence over you is the Sun, which is why most people (incorrectly) say "I am a Taurus" or "I am a Leo" etc. They are really saying, "My Sun was in Leo when I was born." However, all their other planets were very likely not all in Leo, and so nearly everyone is a unique...

Comment: conglomeration of signs and their qualities, unless of course, they were born in the same area at the same moment, and in that case, they would have the same planets in the same signs. The most influential signs are the ones that your Sun, Moon, and Ascending sign were in when you were born. An excellent book for beginners (me) is The Inner Sky by Steven Forrest. I now see that it is available online free here: http://www.nordlicht.ru/stars/english/Steven%20Forrest%20-%20The%20Inner%20Sky.pdf

Comment: @JLee, is this zodiacal belief system saying that everyone on the planet born on a particular day/week have the same behavioral characteristics?

Answer (score 7):

They are:

> Constellations in the Zodiac: Aries,  Leo, and Sagittarius

Answer (score 6):

Partial Answer (Thanks to A E)

Could it be that:

> Aaron is Adrenaline, which makes makes people more adventurous and courageous. Sam is Serotonin, which helps make people 'feel well' and become more optimistic. As for Lenny...He is still a mystery to me.

Answer (score 4):

OK, following the theme of matching initial letters, let's go with

> - Alcohol
>  - Self-esteem, and
>  - Love.

I have severe doubts about at least one of these :-)

---

Let's try these ones:

> - Art
>  - Science
>  - Money (aka filthy Lucre :-) )

... and failing that, totally abandoning first letters:

> - Family
>  - Work
>  - Church

Comment: @JLee - would you prefer I split my answer attempts up, or just append them like this?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, initial gut reaction, because it's 3 elements that influence behavior:

> Id, Ego, and Super-ego

?

Comment: +1 for an answer that makes sense, but none of those are correct.